# NSMutableDictionary weird problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, release

Say I have a class with two NSMutableDictionary.

```
@interface GameDataManager : CCNode {

    NSMutableDictionary *worldInfoDictionary;
    NSMutableDictionary *levelInfoDictionary;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *worldInfoDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *levelInfoDictionary;
```

And I load the data from the plist while the app start like this:

```
-(BOOL) readApplicationData:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSData *myData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appFile] autorelease];

    if (myData == nil) {

       return NO;
    }

    NSKeyedUnarchiver *un = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:myData];
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [un decodeObjectForKey:@"GameData"];

    self.worldInfoDictionary = [dic objectForKey:@"WorldInfoDictionary"];
    self.levelInfoDictionary = [dic objectForKey:@"LevelInfoDictionary"];

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

           WorldInfoData * w = [worldInfoDictionary objectForKey:
                             [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"World%d", i] autorelease]];
    NSLog(@"%d", w.worldNum);
    [w release];
}

    [un finishDecoding];
    [un release];
    return YES; 
}
```

After the next two lines:

```
self.worldInfoDictionary = [dic objectForKey:@"WorldInfoDictionary"];
self.levelInfoDictionary = [dic objectForKey:@"LevelInfoDictionary"];
```

I can see the number of values/keys in two Dictionaries are right.

Then I tried to print out all the "worldNum" value for each object but the app
crahed:

```
2011-03-07 15:18:21.819 [1267:207] 1
2011-03-07 15:18:21.820 [1267:207] 2
2011-03-07 15:18:21.821 [1267:207] 3
2011-03-07 15:18:21.823 [1267:207] 4
2011-03-07 15:18:21.831 [1267:207] 5
2011-03-07 15:18:21.832 [1267:207] 6
2011-03-07 15:18:21.832 [1267:207] 7
2011-03-07 15:18:21.833 [1267:207] 8
2011-03-07 15:18:21.834 [1267:207] 9
2011-03-07 15:18:21.834 [1267:207] 10
Stack dump:
0.  Running pass 'Sparse Conditional Constant Propagation' on function '@gleLLVMVecProjectionTransform2'
```

If I uncomment this line:

```
[un release];
```

The app works fine, no crash.

Can anybody explain this to me, thanks a lot^_^

Thanks for all the answers.

But if I delete the code lines I used to output some info:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

           WorldInfoData * w = [worldInfoDictionary objectForKey:
                  [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"World%d", i] autorelease]];
    NSLog(@"%d", w.worldNum);
    [w release];
}
```

And uncomment the line "[un release];", the readApplicationData works fine,
 but when I tried to read the data later like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [GameDataManager sharedGameDataManager].worldInfoDictionary;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"World%d", i];    
            WorldInfoData *worldInfoData = [dic objectForKey:key];

            if (worldInfoData.worldNum == 1) {
                //......
            }
            [key release];
        }
```

After this line : "WorldInfoData *worldInfoData = [dic objectForKey:key];", the type of worldInfoData 
is not WorldInfoData * but CCArray, and since CCArray don't have property 
worldNum, it crashed......

Comment: What's in the finishDecoding function?

Comment: That is a function of NSKeyedUnarchiver...

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest running your application with Zombie detection enabled.

What you will find is a notification that you are overreleasing 'w'.

```
WorldInfoData * w = [worldInfoDictionary objectForKey:
                         [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"World%d", i] autorelease]];
NSLog(@"%d", w.worldNum);
[w release];
```

You add 'w' to the autorelease pool, but then call release on it explicitly. I would guess that getting rid of the [w release]; line will fix your problem or don't add 'w' to the autorelease pool.

Comment: Almost... the thing that's being explicitly autoreleased is the key. But `w` is being released when it's not an object that this code owns.